# Who is the tall man?

Tags: riddle, knowledge, story

Three men were talking in a bar, after drinking quite a bit. After an intense argument on the state of the city's crime, the tall one of them was indignant that he was right.

He was wearing thick black-rimmed glasses and had his dark hair slicked back, when he changed the subject and said to the other two, "I heard that if you jump out of this particular window, you will fall 20 stories but right before you hit the ground you will float up to the window and land back where you started."

The other two laughed and said it was impossible.

The man said, "I bet you $5,000 it's true".

The other two wiped off the smirked off their faces and got very serious, since $5,000 was about a month's wages. "Hmm, ok, but you have to go first."

The first man agreed. "Ok, I will go first. Now watch."

So, the first man got up onto the ledge of the window, and before the bartender could stop him, he jumped. 20 stories, 19, 18, 17, ... 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 story, and the other two men, leaning over the balcony, stared in amazement as he came from a screaming free fall to an abrupt halt at the first floor, and began floating back up.

A couple minutes later he reached back at the 20th story window and with his arms and legs swinging in the air and a look of bewilderment on his face, he was placed in what seemed like magic right next to the other two men, just as before he had jumped.

All three of their faces matched in total amazement at what just happened. The other two just stared in amazement for a moment, unsure if what they just witnessed was reality; but then after realizing the whole bar was completely silent, they glanced around at the frozen faces fixed on the three of them, and realized that what they just witnessed really happened.

The second man, still drunk, decided in a moment that he was going to try it as well. The third man yelled, **"WAIT!"** but the second man had already jumped.

The first and third man leaned out the window and watched as the second man fell into a freefall, 20 stories, 19, 18, 17, ... 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, ... *SPLAT*. All that was left was a red splat of what used to be a human being.

20 stories up, the remaining two men looked confused. Then the bartender said, "You're a mean drunk, __________".

Who was the tall man?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're a mean drunk

> Superman

He just

> flew back up to the window